# Range of $\frac{1}{2\cos x-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can we find the range of $$f(x) =\frac{1}{2\cos x-1}$$

Since range of $\cos x$ can be given as : $-1 \leq \cos x \leq 1$

therefore we can proceed as :$$\begin{array}{rcl}
 -2 \leq      & 2\cos x                  & \leq 2 \\
 -2-1 \leq    & 2\cos x -1               & \leq 2-1\\ 
 -3 \leq      & 2\cos x -1               & \leq 1 \\
 \frac{-1}{3} \leq & \frac{1}{2\cos x-1} & \leq 1
\end{array}$$

Is it the range? Please suggest and guide.

Comment: It's all good until the last step when you do reciprocals. First, there is $0$ in that range which you cannot do the reciprocal of. Also doing reciprocals reverses the inequalities.

Comment: Yes, consider for example $2<3$.  If you could take reciprocals in the way that you did, you would obtain $\frac12< \frac13$.

Comment: Hi, Sachin: You've asked a bunch of questions at Math.SE, but it seems you haven't been accepting answers. Sometimes users don't know about accepting and upvoting: You can accept one answer per question asked, and you can do so by clicking on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. Plus, you get $2$ reputation points for every answer accepted. You also have plenty enough reputation to upvote as many answers to your question as you'd like!

Comment: For the record, I suggested an edit adding two tags "functions" and "solution-verification", but [it was rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2001885).

Answer (score 5):

As $2\cos x-1$ varies through $[-3,0)$, $\frac{1}{2\cos x-1}$ varies through $(-\infty,-\frac13]$.

As $2\cos x-1$ varies through $(0,1]$, $\frac{1}{2\cos x-1}$ varies through $[1,+\infty)$.

Note that division by $0$ is undefined, so we do not consider the case $2\cos x-1=0$.

Hence the range is $(-\infty,-\frac13]\cup [1,+\infty)$.

Comment: why $2\cos x-1\ne0$?

Comment: Because you cannot divide by $0$.

Answer (score 3):

No, you are fine down to $-3 \le 2\cos x -1 \le 1$, but you need to change the sense of the inequality when  you invert:  Think of a positive $x \le 1$, then $\frac 1x \ge 1$.  The idea is that if the denominator is small (and you have trapped it near $0$) the inverse is large.

Answer (score 0):

I think your calculation is right

Comment: So, for what value of $x$ is $$\frac{1}{2\cos x-1}=0?$$

Comment: This is better as a comment. It would be helpful to provide further technical details in a response, so the OP can understand what you are saying. Regards